# How to define a URL in C#

Tags: c#

I have something like this

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://127.0.0.1/");
```

and I want to use something similar to

```
#define URL @""http://127.0.0.1/"
 WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(URL);
```

How can I do this in C#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C#, you use [`const`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e6w8fe1b.aspx) to declare a constant, as opposed to a `#define`, like in C.

```
const string URL = @"http://127.0.0.1/";
```

Answer (score 12):

I'm not sure if I undrstand you correctly but if you want to define an URL, you don't need to create a WebRequest...

You should use Uri type for example:

```
Uri ur = new Uri("http://www.google.com");
```

Here some example how you can retrieve data from Uri type:

```
    Console.WriteLine("AbsolutePath = {0}", uri.AbsolutePath);
    Console.WriteLine("AbsoluteUri = {0}", uri.AbsoluteUri);
    Console.WriteLine("Authority = {0}", uri.Authority);
    Console.WriteLine("DnsSafeHost = {0}", uri.DnsSafeHost);
    Console.WriteLine("Fragment = {0}", uri.Fragment);
    Console.WriteLine("Host = {0}", uri.Host);
    Console.WriteLine("HostNameType = {0}", uri.HostNameType);
    Console.WriteLine("IsAbsoluteUri = {0}", uri.IsAbsoluteUri);
    Console.WriteLine("IsDefaultPort = {0}", uri.IsDefaultPort);
    Console.WriteLine("IsFile = {0}", uri.IsFile);
    Console.WriteLine("IsLoopback = {0}", uri.IsLoopback);
    Console.WriteLine("IsUnc = {0}", uri.IsUnc);
    Console.WriteLine("LocalPath = {0}", uri.LocalPath);
    Console.WriteLine("OriginalString = {0}", uri.OriginalString);
    Console.WriteLine("PathAndQuery = {0}", uri.PathAndQuery);
    Console.WriteLine("Port = {0}", uri.Port);
    Console.WriteLine("Query = {0}", uri.Query);
    Console.WriteLine("Scheme = {0}", uri.Scheme);
    Console.WriteLine("Segments = {0}", string.Join(",", uri.Segments));
    Console.WriteLine("UserEscaped = {0}", uri.UserEscaped);
    Console.WriteLine("UserInfo = {0}", uri.UserInfo);
    Console.WriteLine(new string('-', 40));
```

see more info [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/uri)

Comment: But `Uri` allows something like `www.example.org`, which isn't a valid URL (but is a valid URI)